# What is the better way to rename columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, rename

Maybe somewhere out on SO there is a discussion on that, so please link then.
How to better rename columns in case you want to add specific conditions or start only in a particular place. For example, I use list comprehensions where you can add conditions, slices, etc.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [i for i in range(2)],
                  'b':[i for i in range(2)]})
print(df)
df.columns.values[1:] = [f'{name}_c' for name in df.columns[1:]]
print(df)
```

Out:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1

   a  b_c
0  0    0
1  1    1
```

Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I like the rename method:

```
df.rename(columns={name: f'{name}_c' for name in df.columns[1:]})
```